# Shell command for in-place multi-line regex replace

Tags: ruby, regex

With single line regex you can use `-p` and `$_.sub!`:

```
$ cat file.txt
<a
a>
c
$ ruby -i -pe '$_.sub!("a", "b")' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
<b
b>
c
```

Is there any short way to replace multi-line patterns? I currently use something like this:

```
$ ruby -i -e 'print *readlines.join.sub(/<.*>/m, "d")' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
d
c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gets(nil)` saves you a whopping 6 characters :)

```
ruby -i -e 'print gets(nil).sub(/<.*>/m, "d")' file.txt
```

From the `gets` [docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/gets):

> > The optional argument specifies the record separator. The separator is included with the contents of each record. A separator of nil reads the entire contents. [...]